# R: "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" but works with another similar dataset?

Tags: r, function, loops, character

I have the following function "cOrder"

```
library(MASS)

cOrder=function(anm,sir,dam){
  maxloop=1000
  i = 1
  count = 0
  mam=length(anm)
  old = rep(1,mam)
  new = old
  while(i>0){
    for (j in 1:mam){
      ks = sir[j]
      kd = dam[j]
      gen = new[j]+1
      if(ks != "NA"){
      js = match(ks,anm)
        if(gen > new[js]){new[js] = gen}  #where error occurs
      }
      if(kd != "NA"){
        jd = match(kd,anm)
        if(gen > new[jd]){new[jd] = gen}
      }
    }   # for loop
    changes = sum(new - old)
    old = new
    i = changes
    count = count + 1
    if(count > maxloop){i=0}
      }   # while loop
  return(new)
}  # function loop
```

which works brilliantly when imputting the following
dataset:

```
animal=c("bf","dd","ga","ec","fb","ag","he")
sire=c("dd","ga","NA","ga","NA","bf","dd")
dams=c("he","ec","NA","fb","NA","ec","fb")
gg=cOrder(animal,sire,dams)
```

but crashes and burns with the following:

```
animal=c("67947887","67947986","67948372","67948877","67948927","67949057","67950873","67951186","67951285","67951384","67951400","67951525","67951681","68045244","68045657","69999837","77542587","77542629","78468170","79879946")
sire=c("45334307","45334307","40684433","38121933","38141933","40684433","43339787","38431722","40684433","43339787","34931873","40684433","34931873","67951525","67951525","67950873","67951400","67951384","NA","67951681")
dams=c("37084407","25565110","36817369","21897145","21897145","20138814","32629901","37485356","25731548","32129629","31795768","37588084","36812355","68040013","68040500","68040443","67951855","67950980","67949065","67948307")
gg=cOrder(animal,sire,dams) 

>Error in if (gen > new[js]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Both of these are inputted as character vectors, so I don't think it is a matter of whether the one set have characters and the other numeric digits. Or could it? Have also tried to make them numeric, import from a .csv, unlist them, etc. Error code stays the same.

My individual names generally consist of 8-digit numeric codes, any suggestions towards preventing this error, or renaming my whole population?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The way the datasets are setup is as follows: the first animal in the vector is the offspring of the first dam and sire in their respective vectors. Thus, according the the simple set, bf is the offspring of dd and he, dd of ga and ec, and the parents of ga are unknown.

The idea behind this function is to determine the "oldest" animal/s in the dataset, i.e., the ones with the least number of generations, and eventually in succeeding code order them accordingly and generate a relationship matrix. So it is supposed to be OK if an animal does not appear in the sire list; it means that it is an older animal. So the code is supposed to move on to the next. Which it does in the simple set, but not in the proper one. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: According to `?match`, it returns `NA` by default when there's no match.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I do however have several animals in common between the animal and sire datasets, such as 67951525 and 67951400 (similar to bf and dd in the dataset that works), so why the missing value error?

Comment: You only need one that isn't in common to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your first sire value (45334307) doesn't match anything in your animal list, so match() returns an NA.